# how do sites like toufee or mouvee work ?

Tags: flash, compilation, flv

Was just wondering how do these sites (and many other softwares that generate flash movies from audio clips,images , docs) work ? how do they compile the media files(audio/image/vid) into a flv movie on the server ? Can the same be done using some open source tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://osflash.org/open_source_flash_projects

Answer (score 0):

They probably just upload the file and then run a tool like [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) on them.

A php example to convert any audio file (that ffmpeg can handle) to an mp3 would be like this:

```
<?php
// upload audio file and save its file name as $file_name

$short_name = substr($file_name, 0, strpos($file_name, ".")); // get the file name without the file extension

system("ffmpeg -i \"$file_name\" \"$short_name.mp3\"");
?>
You can download your file <a href="output.mp3">here</a>
```

You'd probably want to make it more secure, but that should work. I'm actually not too sure about the ffmpeg command line options, but you can find more info here: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html

Comment: don't think so, they provide all sorts of options like transitions, filters .. ffmpeg won't be able to do that